# jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.d.ts / jquery.validate.unobtrusive.d.ts anyone?

Tags: typescript, web-essentials

I'm trying to convert my app.js to app.ts and the only thing missing is a .d file for jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and/or jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.

When I build and compile with tsc it works fine but WebEssentials in VS2012 complains about :

```
var $form = $('#myform');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
```

Error:

```
The property 'unobtrusive' does not exist on value of type 'Validator'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't got type information, and the compiler can't infer a type then there will be a problem.

Although you are getting output from the command line I would still expect it to give an error. Web Essentials enforces things more strongly, which is the idea behind the tooling.

If you can't get type information (check Definitely Typed on GitHub) you can fix the error using a simplified definition...

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    validator: any;
}
```

If you have a definition for validator, you could use this trick to declare unobtrusive against that, which would then only have missing type information rather than all of validator.

This will lose typing on validator but will fix the error.

Taken from http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/

Comment: Sorry - in my head I thought the second line used the form selected in the first line! I will update.

Comment: Thanks again, but I couldnt get that to work either.  It complains about a duplicate definition - from jquery.validate.d.ts I guess.  I solved it another way.  See my answer.  Cheers

Comment: In that case you probably already have the jQuery validation definition, which you could extend as I described. If you do it with a cast, you litter your code with casts that need to be removed when you add a definition.

Comment: @SteveFenton NuGet now has a 'jquery-validation-unobtrusive.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped' package for this.

Answer (score 4):

Just to illustrate what I think Steve has already said, if you [download the d.ts from DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery.validation/jquery.validation.d.ts), and open up the file, you will see the `Validator` interface (among other definitions). It is simple to extend it:

```
interface Validator {
    format(template: string, ...arguments: string[]): string;
    form(): bool;
    element(element: any): bool;
    resetForm(): void;
    showErrors(errors: any): void;
    numberOfInvalids(): number;
    setDefaults(defaults: ValidationOptions): void;
    addMethod(name: string, method: (value: any, element: any, ...params: any[]) => any, message?: any): void;
    addClassRules(rules: any): void;
    addClassRules(name: string, rules: any): void;

    // Just add the unobtrusive element to this (typed as `any` if you don't have time to do anything more)
    unobtrusive:any; 
}
```

The rest of the work of extending the `JQuery` and `JQueryStatic` interfaces is already done for you, elsewhere in the file. You won't get any typed goodness on the `unobtrusive` element, but at least all the rest of the `Validator` code will be type checked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by casting to any:

```
(<any>$.validator).unobtrusive.parse($form);
```

I do like typescript but use of it is hampered by the lack of definition files.  I guess that's a small thing - tsc works fine - but if Visual Studio is going to complain about simple things like this then it's going to be a problem for a lot of people.

Comment: -1 I don't think this is the best solution, and I disagree that TS is hampered by the reliance on d.ts files. VS has to 'complain' about even simple things, otherwise what use is a Typed system? I think most developers using TS will be delighted to discover how many definition files the community has already assembled, and will find the process of adding to or extending this library quick and straightforward.

Comment: Correct, it is not the best solution but the lack of the .d file for this library Definitely hampered me.  Extending it might be quick and straightforward for some, but I think typescript is different enough to make it non trivial - there is some learning required.